# Chrome for Android contenteditable bug

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, contenteditable

I am encountering a strange bug with contentedtible elements in Chrome for Android (v3.1.0.1650.59).

```
<div contenteditable="true">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur, mi euismod
</div>
```

When the user gives focus to the input and taps the end of the input to move their cursor to the end, [the spell check line is not in the correct location - it is several characters off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1Pam.png). Then, when the user hits the delete character, [part of the text before the carrot get scrambled about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVoGG.png).

This seems to only be an issue if the last word in the input is spelled wrong so the autocorrect suggestions are displayed. If the last word is spelled correctly, the issue is nonexistent.

Code can be found here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29148332/contenteditable.html

Is there something in my markup/css that is triggering this issue, or is this a Chrome for Android bug?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is a bug with Android's WebView class that has apparently been a known issue since 2013. I have spent hours trying to fix it because it is unbearable, and learned that what is happening is that the keyboard is falling behind the content in the  element, causing these weird cursor placement and autocorrect issues. It hasn't been fixed in 3 years, apparently, so I'm guessing something is horribly wrong.

From a design standpoint, your best bet is to force Android users to suck it up, or have some unformatted plain text editor that supports basic HTML elements or bbcode.